# duplicate entry: META-INF/myLibrary.kotlin_module

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

After updating to Android 3.0, getting Kotlin error:

```
Execution failed for task ':myLibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/myLibrary.kotlin_module
```

This is my library buid.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

...

dependencies {
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

This is my project build.gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is so annoying, but running **Clean Project** fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a cache error (with kotlin) to me. Running `gradle clean` or `gradle clear` (not sure which is the right spelling, sorry, one of these should exist as a gradle task) and rebuilding should fix the error, because all files in cache will be deleted by the task and regenerated by the project build.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer in mobile app when I wrote mine. Not sure if I should delete it though?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your build.gradle . in packagingOptions:

```
packagingOptions {
    ...
    exclude 'META-INF/rxkotlin.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxkotlin_main.kotlin_module'
}
```